# Reference same cell in different sheets and workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, foreach

I need to create a table with references of the same cell in different sheets and workbooks.
In the following link you can find what i mean, but it works only for different sheets in same workbook (the one that contain macro).
I would like to extend it to other 2 or more workbooks (same cell, in each sheets of each workbooks in the specified windows directory).

Go to the vba code in this page (this version of code is more then what i need, after you can see a lighter code that I have modified)
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1337-excel-reference-same-cell-different-sheet.html

```
Public Sub abc()
    Dim Wbook           As Workbook
    Dim WSheet          As Worksheet

Dim FSO             As Object
Dim ExcelFile       As Object
Dim MyFolder        As Object

Dim MyFolderPath    As String
Dim CurrSheet       As String
Dim a               As Long

' Define the path of your folder here
MyFolderPath = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Cartella\"

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Stop the macro if the folder is not found
If Not FSO.FolderExists(MyFolderPath) Then
    MsgBox "Cannot find the specified folder!", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error"
    Exit Sub
End If

Set MyFolder = FSO.GetFolder(MyFolderPath)
CurrSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Loop through all files from the folder selected
For Each ExcelFile In MyFolder.Files

    ' Make sure we check only Excel files
    If Left(FSO.GetExtensionName(ExcelFile.Path), 2) = "xl" Then
        a = 0

        ' Open the workbook (except the workbook that runs the code)
        If ExcelFile.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name And Left(ExcelFile.Name, 2) <> "~$" Then
            Set Wbook = Workbooks.Open(MyFolderPath & ExcelFile.Name)
        Else
            Set Wbook = ThisWorkbook
        End If

        ' Loop through workbook's sheets
        For Each WSheet In Wbook.Worksheets

            If WSheet.Name <> CurrSheet Then
                    'In the masterFile I have a table (inside "Resume" sheet) with: first column Sheet names of all sheets in all workbooks
                    'Second column: a reference formula of each Q32 cells in all worksheets of all workbooks

                    'The next 2 lines are not working (also because I dont know the correct syntax) but It's only to explain what I mean
                    Workbooks("MasterFile").Worksheets("Resume").Range("A4").Offset(a, 0).Value = WSheet.Name
                    Workbooks("MasterFile").Worksheets("Resume").Range("B4").Offset(a, 0).Value = "=[Wbook.Name]WSheet.Name!Q32"

                a = a + 1
            End If
        Next WSheet

        ' Close and save the workbooks (only save the workbook that runs the code)
        If ExcelFile.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name And Left(ExcelFile.Name, 2) <> "~$" Then
            Wbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
        Else
            Wbook.Save
        End If

        Set Wbook = Nothing
    End If
Next ExcelFile

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FileSystemObject is great for this job, see the code below.
This should loop through each Excel file in a folder selected in "MyFolderPath" variable.

Now if you want to include the Workbook that runs the code, you must also place it in that folder.

<s>Another thing I've noticed in your current code (and I kept it that way) is that you have a condition to not write in the sheets which have the same name as the sheet where you run the macro from (it's the activesheet).</s>

If you're going to keep this, make sure that your sheets from other workbooks don't share the name, otherwise they'll be skipped.

EDIT: *Updated based on OP's latest details*

It will add the worksheet name and a reference to the cell Q32 from each workbook scanned, including the master workbook (if placed in the folder only), to the master sheet starting with the 4th row.

It should skip the "Resume" master sheet, but only from the master workbook - if you have another sheet named like the master one, but in a different workbook, that will be checked as any other sheet.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub LoopThroughFiles()
    Dim Wbook           As Workbook
    Dim WSheet          As Worksheet

    Dim FSO             As Object
    Dim ExcelFile       As Object
    Dim MyFolder        As Object

    Dim MyFolderPath    As String
    Dim MasterSheet     As String
    Dim IsMasterFile    As Boolean
    Dim a               As Long

    ' Define the path of your folder here
    MyFolderPath = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Cartella\"
    MasterSheet = "Resume"

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    ' Stop the macro if the folder is not found
    If Not FSO.FolderExists(MyFolderPath) Then
        MsgBox "Cannot find the specified folder!", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set MyFolder = FSO.GetFolder(MyFolderPath)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' Loop through all files from the folder selected
    For Each ExcelFile In MyFolder.Files

        ' Make sure we check only Excel files (and ignore the temp files)
        If Left(FSO.GetExtensionName(ExcelFile.Path), 2) = "xl" And Left(ExcelFile.Name, 2) <> "~$" Then

            ' Reset flag
            IsMasterFile = False

            ' Open the workbook, except the master workbook which is already opened
            If ExcelFile.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
                Set Wbook = Workbooks.Open(MyFolderPath & ExcelFile.Name)
            Else
                Set Wbook = ThisWorkbook
                IsMasterFile = True
            End If

            ' Loop through workbook's sheets
            For Each WSheet In Wbook.Worksheets

                ' Don't check the "Resume" sheet from master workbook
                If IsMasterFile And WSheet.Name = MasterSheet Then GoTo Skip

                With WSheet
                    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(MasterSheet).Range("A4").Offset(a, 0).Value2 = .Name
                    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(MasterSheet).Range("B4").Offset(a, 0).Value2 = "='[" & Wbook.Name & "]" & .Name & "'!" & "Q32"
                End With

                a = a + 1
Skip:
            Next WSheet

            ' Close the workbooks except the master one
            If IsMasterFile = False Then Wbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
            Set Wbook = Nothing
        End If
    Next ExcelFile

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer! I have a problem to define the folder path: My folder is C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Cartella\.    But I am not able to insert that in the code ( MyFolderPath = Environ("UserProfile") & Application.PathSeparator & "Desktop\MyFolder" ). Where do I have to write it here?

Comment: You only replace the last string after the "&" symbol:
`"Desktop\MyFolder"` -> `"Desktop\Cartella"`

Or if it's less confusing, you can just replace the entire line `MyFolderPath = Environ("UserProfile") & Application.PathSeparator & "Desktop\MyFolder"` with `MyFolderPath = "C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Cartella"`

Comment: Thank you! But macro starts, and after opening the first file, it gives a "runtime error 9 Subscript out of range (Error 9)" on this `Set WBook = Workbooks.Open(MyFolderPath & Application.PathSeparator & ExcelFile.Name)`.

Comment: Hey. I've updated the code. Give it another try and make sure to edit the folder path with your user profile name. I've also added a way to not attempt to open the current workbook since you will have it in the same folder.

I did a couple of tests and it went fine, let me know if you have more issues with it.

Comment: I am sorry but probably there is a misunderstanding, and the fault is mine. I update my first code with yours. in the central cicle IF I have added comments to explain better my problem.

Comment: Updated the code again. This will add each sheet name from each workbook (including the master workbook) in the folder, to the "Resume" sheet along with a reference to the cell Q32. I've added a variable that holds the master sheet name (under the path variable).

Comment: THANK YOU ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! That's amazing!